# UrlManager динамические параметры

Tags: yii2

Как описать правило в UrlManager для неопределённого количества параметров. Которые идут в формате **/ключ/значение**

> site/test/a/1/b/2/с/3
>
> site/test/a/1/с/3

```
SiteController->actionTest($a=null, $b=null, $c=null)
```

Регулярка для этого что-то вроде такого получается. Но как теперь настроить UrlManager?

```
site\/test((\/\w+\/\d+){1,})
```

**Updated**

Может это из-за модульной структуры? Сейчас конфиг выглядит так

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'enableStrictParsing' => false,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        //'site/test' => 'web/default/index',
        'site/test/*' => 'web/default/index',
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно указать что бы реагировать на любое значение:

```
'site/test/*'=>'site/test'
```

Update

Действительно в yii2 знак * экранируется, в отличии от yii1.x .
Простого способа не нашел (ранее с подобной задачей не сталкивался), возможно кто то подскажет как сделать иначе.

Вижу два варианта.

Первый самый простой:

```
//действие
public function actionIndex(){
    var_dump($_GET);
}

//правило
'site/test'=>'web/default/index'
```

Тут все просто, убираем из действия все параметры, и просто смотрим в переменной $_GET. Но остается проблема с созданием урл.

Тут так же два варианта:

Переопределить метод `UrlManager::createUrl()`, примерно:

```
namespace app\components;

class UrlManager extends \yii\web\UrlManager
{
    public function createUrl($params, $showParams=true)
    {
        $url = parent::createUrl($params);
        if($showParams){
            $url = str_replace(['?', '=', '&'], '/', $url);
        }else{
            $data = explode('?', $url);
            if(isset($data[1])){
                preg_match_all('/\=(.*?)(?:&|$)/', $data[1], $matches);
                $url = $data[0].'/'.implode('/', $matches[1]);
            }
        }
        return $url;
    }
}
```

в конфиге:

```
'components' => [
    'urlManager' => [
        'class'=>'app\components\UrlManager',
...
```

получаем урл:

```
\yii\helpers\Url::to(['web/default/index', 'a'=>1, 'b'=>2], true);
```

или

```
Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['composerGui/default/test-test', 'a'=>1])
```

Во втором случае можно скрыть название параметров, передав второй параметр `false`

Так же можно переопределить метод `Url::to()`, [примерно](https://gist.github.com/bookin/2245345c10a3333d25e31fb962b57174):

```
namespace app\components;

use yii\helpers\BaseUrl;

class Url extends BaseUrl
{
    public static function to($url = '', $scheme = false, $showParams=true){
        $url = parent::to($url, $scheme);
        if($showParams){
            $url = str_replace(['?', '=', '&'], '/', $url);
        }else{
            $data = explode('?', $url);
            if(isset($data[1])){
                preg_match_all('/\=(.*?)(?:&|$)/', $data[1], $matches);
                $url = $data[0].'/'.implode('/', $matches[1]);
            }
        }
        return $url;
    }
}
```

Использовать:

```
\app\components\Url::to(['site/test', 'a'=>1, 'b'=>2], true);
```

или что бы скрыть название параметров:

```
\app\components\Url::to(['site/test', 'a'=>1, 'b'=>2], true, false);
```

Ну тут выбирать уже что лучше только вам.

Второй вариант для написания правил, это написать свой класс для правил, примерно:

````
namespace app\components;

use yii\web\Request;
use yii\web\UrlManager;
use yii\web\UrlRule;

/**
 * AnyParamsRule represents a rule used by [[UrlManager]] for parsing and generating URLs with an unknown number of parameters.
 *
 * ```php
 * 'rules' => [
 *     [
 *          'class' => 'app\components\AnyParamsRule',
 *          'pattern' => 'tyt/test', //wat url do you want see
 *          'route' => 'site/index', //what action will be executed
 *          'showParams'=>true, //need show parameters on the url or not /site/index/param1/val1/param2/val2 or /site/index/val1/val2
 *          'defaults'=>['a'=>null, 'b'=>null, 'c'=>null] //if showParams is false need write all parameters what will be
 *     ],
 *     // ...
 * ]
 * ```
 *
 * @author Bookin <issues.bookin@gmail.com>
 */
class AnyParamsRule extends UrlRule
{

    public $showParams = false;

    /**
     * Creates a URL according to the given route and parameters.
     * @param UrlManager $manager the URL manager
     * @param string $route the route. It should not have slashes at the beginning or the end.
     * @param array $params the parameters
     * @return string|boolean the created URL, or `false` if this rule cannot be used for creating this URL.
     */
    public function createUrl($manager, $route, $params){
        $url = false;
        $sep = '/';
        if($this->route == $route){
            $url = $this->name;
            if($this->showParams === true){
                foreach( $params as $key => $value ) {
                    $url .= $sep . $key . ':' . $value;
                }
            }else{
                $url.=$sep.implode($sep, $params);
            }
        }

        return $url;
    }

    /**
     * Parses the given request and returns the corresponding route and parameters.
     * @param UrlManager $manager the URL manager
     * @param Request $request the request component
     * @return array|boolean the parsing result. The route and the parameters are returned as an array.
     * If `false`, it means this rule cannot be used to parse this path info.
     */
    public function parseRequest($manager, $request){
        $pathInfo = $request->getPathInfo();
        $attributes = [];

        if(stristr($pathInfo, $this->name) === false){
            return false;
        }

        $params = str_replace($this->name, '', $pathInfo);
        $params = ltrim($params, '/');
        if($params){
            $params = array_filter(explode('/', $params));
            $params_length = count($params);
            if($this->showParams === true){
                foreach ($params as $i=>$param){
                    if(($i+1)%2 == 0){
                        $attributes[$params[$i-1]]=$param;
                    }else{
                        $attributes[$params[$i]]='';
                    }

                }
            }else if(is_array($this->defaults) && $params_length <= ($defaults_length = count($this->defaults))){
                $fake = array_fill($params_length,$defaults_length-$params_length, null);
                $attributes = array_combine(array_keys($this->defaults), $params+$fake);
            }else{
                $attributes = false;
            }
        }

        foreach ($this->defaults as $name => $value) {
            if (!isset($attributes[$name]) || ($attributes[$name] === null && $value != null)) {
                $attributes[$name] = $value;
            }
        }

        if($attributes === false){
            return false;
        }else{
            return ['composerGui/default/test-test', $attributes];
        }
    }

}
````

Использование:

Для url вида - `site/test/a/1` или `site/test/a/1/b/2` или `site/test/a/1/b/2/c/3`

```
'rules' => [
    ...
    [
        'class' => 'app\components\AnyParamsRule',
        'pattern' => 'site/test',
        'route'=>'web/default/index'
    ],
    ...
```

Для url вида - `site/test/1` или `site/test/1/2` или `site/test/1/2/3`

```
'rules' => [
    ...
    [
        'class' => 'app\components\AnyParamsRule',
        'pattern' => 'site/test',
        'route'=>'web/default/index',
        'showParams'=>false,
        'defaults'=>['a'=>null, 'b'=>null, 'c'=>null] //можно указать параметры по умолчанию
    ],
```

Для генерирования урлов используем стандартный компонент:

```
\yii\helpers\Url::to(['web/default/index', 'a'=>1], true)
```

P.S. Код не является истиной, и может упускать какие либо моменты или иметь ошибки, буду благодарен за отзывы в [gist](https://gist.github.com/bookin/2245345c10a3333d25e31fb962b57174) что бы исправить ошибки и недочеты

Comment: Cтранно. По идее должно отрабатывать. Но не работает. 404 вылетает.

Comment: Спасибо. Наверно остановлюсь на втором варианте, он мне кажется более правильным, хоть и сложным. Сейчас возможности проверить нет. Но с виду похоже что должно работать.